# Asterisk icon in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to use glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk icon in Bootstrap Navbar? I want to add a red asterisk icon next to text for a tab in navbar navbar-default, to show it is mandatory, and also at the bottom of the page I want to give a label for asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>` next to your menu button

Here is a demo link

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_asterisk&stacked=h

Mark this as the answer if it helped you. Hope this helps.

Comment: What are the libraries that I need to include ?

Comment: You need to have glyphicons in the fonts folder and include the font face in the page you want to use the glyphs in. Here's a link to the components http://getbootstrap.com/components/ . And here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL8xyFWM2BA

Comment: Please mark this as the answer for other users to reference. The tutorial should explain everything.